# How to make Illustrator not to lie about colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-reproduction

Here is the fragment of red area, which is said by Illustrator as being `#840608` (upper green marker). But actually, as reported by screen inspecting application, the color is `#9C0D01` (lower gree marker).

[image]

Later, when I starting to export image for web, the color is becoming `#B70F00`

[image]

Finally it becomes `#9B0203` in we browser:

[image]

How professional program can be so inaccurate with colors? If this is a result of some feature (the usability of one is of high doubt) the how is it possible to disable it totally?

So, I need color code conserve full way from drawing to web.

**UPDATE**

I am measuring screen colors with [Instant Eyedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/) utility. It works exact with web browsers:

[image]

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/VT8T4/

**UPDATE 2**

Illustrator file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8pZ9a2478YNzVBejVsM21fWFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How are you measuring the color in your screen, and what format are you saving your images in? Because low quality JPGs can export the 'wrong' colors.

Comment: Just checking: the document colour mode is definitely RGB? Not CMYK?

Comment: be sure to export to RGB with profile embedded

Comment: @Yisela I am exporting to `PNG`, you can notice transparent section in sawe to web dialog screenshot.

Comment: @user568458 yes, document color mode is `RGB`

Comment: Calibrate your monitor and ensure you are using the proper color settings (Edit menu) within Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott, suppose I have no monitor. Described phenomena do not depend on it.

Comment: If you have no monitor.. you don't need a web browser.... Adobe apps read your monitor color profile (created when the monitor is calibrated) then use the Color Settings within the apps to control color.

Comment: I understand that it is annoying when something doesn't work the way you expect, but be cautious with statements like "How professional program can be so inaccurate with colors?" The truth, as Scott's answer shows, is that professional programs require professional knowledge. Until you are expert, always assume that you made a mistake or there is something you don't know. You will learn more quickly if you do that.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Scott's answer shows that `AI` is just buggy. Switching to `RGB` mode should either not permitted, or should leave no traces of previous mode. Partial switching IS a bug. Of course, professionalism includes knowing such bugs and knowing workarounds, here I agree.

Comment: @Scott calibrating concerns the physical representation of colors. It should never convert explicitly entered digital data.

Comment: Dims, no.. Illustrator is **not** "buggy" in this instance. It's a matter of understanding how color works and output. The applications can't read your mind.

Comment: And calibration values are used in the display of colors on screen. An incorrect calibration can **wildly** alter the colors Adobe apps show you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay... here's your issue.

You started a new Illustrator document in CMYK mode. Then at some point later, you switched the **Document Color Mode** to RGB. This causes the document to *still use the color settings for CMYK*. In fact, when you simply switch color modes on the fly *many* things within Illustrator stick to the *old* color mode - the color profiles, the libraries (swatches, symbols, brushes, etc.).

When creating a new file in Illustrator you need to **start with the color mode needed for output** in order to maintain color. This is *especially true* for RGB since the CMYK gamut is so much smaller. Switching color modes mid-document will *often* have unexplained results where color is concerned.

How do I know this..... download your Illustrator file and open it.

- The **Swatch Panel** is loaded with CMYK color even though to document color mode is RGB. That doesn't happen if you start with an RGB document.
- Copy your red button. Create a new **RGB** document and `Paste`. The color is `#9a0203` (which is as close as CMYK can get to `#840608`).

Now, in an **RGB Document** set the color to `#840608` and it will match your browser colors.