# How to change document color mode in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, rgb

I have document with some color. I can't reproduce this color exactly when exporting to web. [I was told](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/how-to-make-illustrator-not-to-lie-about-colors), that this is because of the bug, by which Illustrator is not changing color mode with menu

[image]

and it is required to create new document for this setting take an effect.

If this true, then how to copy all data from old document to the new one, including artboard size and location?

Comment: You can't copy artboard sizes and locations between documents. You *can* draw rectangles where your artboards are and copy those along with other art. Then after pasting, convert those rectangles to artboards.

Comment: @Scott please, how to do this exactly?

Comment: @Dims make the rectangle, bring that rectangle to which document you want the new artboard in. Open the artboard panel (window - artboard). Select the rectangle, (on the artboard panel) click on the dropdown arrow to select "Convert to Artboards".

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to create a new document, you are able to change the color mode.

First go to **File** → **Document Color Mode** and Change it to `CMYK` or `RGB` - Depending on what you need.

Then open the Color window - **Window** → **Color** (or hit <kbd>F6</kbd>)

---

> Click on the drop down menu in the top right

[image]

> Switch from CMYK to RGB

[image]

---

> You can then click on any object in the file and it should come up in
>   `RGB` colors (or `CMYK` if switching vice-versa).

Comment: Note that **libraries** (swatches, brushes, styles, etc) are all built in the **original** document color mode. If you open an RGB document... all the libraries are RGB. If you then change that RGB document mode to CMYK... all the libraries are **still** RGB.  If you want a complete color mode change, including Libraries, it is best to copy artwork, create a **new document** in the desired color mode, then paste. That way all your swatches, brushes, styles, etc are in the same color mode as the document.